# Can a ProjectTemplate archive be stored within a Visual Studio solution, similar to the way CodeTemplates (.tt) files work?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template, code-templates

There are many blog posts out there that show you how to create and include **T4** (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) files **(.tt)** in your solution and have them override those stored in the default Visual Studio location. (see bottom of question for links)

**Question:**

Can you create and include a project Template file in a Visual Studio solution? If so what is required for Visual Studio to detect and use it.

A project template archive contains a .csproj, .vstemplate, and .cs files in them.

**Example:**

```
**ClassLibrary.zip**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ClassLibrary.zip
```

The .tt files seem to just work as soon as you add them, this doesn't seem to be the case for the template zip files...

**Code Template Posts:**

> [Hanselman - T4 Code Generation - Best Kept Visual Studio Secret](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)
>
> [Conery - Make Visual Studio Generate Your Repository](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/make-visual-studio-generate-your-repository/)
>
> [Haack - Creating a Custom ASP.NET MVC Project Template](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you export the template using the wizard (File/Export Template) so you have a zipped up template package, then you can use a project with a post-build step to copy the template to the following location:

```
<userdir>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\<lang>
```

That location is read dynamically, so it should appear in VS next time you open the File/New project dialog.